# Generic decode function not working (Swift)

Tags: swift, generics, decoder, decodable, jsondecoder

I'm trying to create a generic decode function to decode my two different models. I get the error "Argument type 'PrivateSchoolType.Type' does not conform to expected type 'Decodable'".

Model

```
struct PrivateSchoolModel: Decodable {
    var name: String
    var id: String
    var city: String
    var state: String
}
```

Calling Function

```
function getInfo() {
    // does not work => ERROR
    guard let schools = decode(jsonData: jsonData, using: PrivateSchoolModel) else { return }

    // does work
    guard let schools = specificDecode()
}
```

Specific Decode Function (DOES WORK)

```
private func specificDecode() -> [PrivateSchoolModel]? {
    guard let jsonData = getJSONData(from: .privateSchool) else { return }
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let schools = try decoder.decode([PrivateSchoolModel].self, from:
            jsonData)
            return schools

        } catch let error {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        return nil
}
```

Generic Decode Function (DOES NOT WORK)

```
private func decode<M: Decodable>(jsonData: Data, using model: M) -> [M]? {
        do {
            //here dataResponse received from a network request
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let schools = try decoder.decode([M].self, from:
                jsonData) //Decode JSON Response Data

            return schools
        } catch let parsingError {
            print("Error", parsingError)
        }

        return nil
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't `using model: M` be `using decoder: M`?

Comment: Can you show `PublicSchoolModel` and how that is related to `PrivateSchoolModel`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the method `signature` as below,

```
private func decode<M: Decodable>(jsonData: Data, using modelType: M.Type) -> M? {
    do {
        //here dataResponse received from a network request
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let schools = try decoder.decode(modelType, from: jsonData) //Decode JSON Response Data
        return schools
    } catch let parsingError {
        print("Error", parsingError)
    }
    return nil
}
```

**Usage**

```
guard let schools = decode(jsonData: jsonData, using: [PublicSchoolModel].self) else { return }
```

Comment: Perfect. If you have a minute, could you briefly explain why you have to do it that or point me to a resource?